# Use newrelic in nuxt

Tags: node.js, newrelic, nuxt.js

I am trying to add newrelic agent to my nuxt application. I have installed the needed package and added my license key and set an application name in `newrelic.js` configuration file:

```
npm i newrelic
cp node_modules/newrelic/newrelic.js .
nano newrelic.js
```

My problem is that I also need to require this configuration file at the top of my `server.js` file and since this file is dynamically created and placed under the `.nuxt` folder I have no idea how to do this.

In a standard nodejs application I would simply add the `require('newrelic');` to the top of my startup script or perhaps add a new script entry in `package.json` looking something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node -r newrelic.js app.js"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `express` to solve this:

```
npm i express
touch server/index.js
```

We will now load `newrelic` in the `server/index.js` file and after that create our nuxt instance:

```
require('newrelic');
const express = require('express');
const consola = require('consola');
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
const app = express();

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js');
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

async function start () {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server;

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
    await builder.build();
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready();
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render);

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host);
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  });
}
start();
```

I also updated the `script` section in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
  "build": "nuxt build",
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js"
}
```

Hope this can help anyone who faces the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Node.js, you can *require* a module with the `-r [module]` syntax (see [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/cli.html#-r---require-module)) before your actual script starts up.

For Nuxt, alter your npm run scripts like this (instead `nuxt start`):

```shell
node -r newrelic node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js start
```

This way, Node loads NewRelic first, then Nuxt, and ensures NewRelic is able to instrument all dependencies. If you let Nuxt bootup first, NewRelic is not aware of some dependencies, e.g. *express*.

This is recommended by NewRelic, see [their docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/install-nodejs-agent/#installing).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this I found a much simpler solution by using Nuxt [modules](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/modules) and [hooks](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/internals-nuxt#hooks).

Create a new file `modules/newRelic.js` with the following content:

```
module.exports = function () {
  this.nuxt.hook("listen", () => {
    require("newrelic");
  });
};
```

Import the module in `nuxt.config.js`

```
modules: [
  "~/modules/newRelic.js"
]
```

Don't forget to install newrelic (`npm i newrelic`) and paste `newrelic.js` into the applications root folder.

Comment: The problem here is that NewRelic doesn't start early enough to instrument modules/libraries which are already loaded, e.g. express.