# How can i use Newrelic with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, newrelic

I want to monitor my nuxt app in server side and I found newrelic. Probably it's best way.

I didn't find any good resource for this subject. Maybe I should use newrelic with nuxt one.

Any suggest or experience?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use newrelic in nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370357/use-newrelic-in-nuxt)

Comment: @NicolasPennec hello, i dont want to use express, any another example do you have?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggling with this I found a solution by using Nuxt [modules](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/modules) and [hooks](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/internals-nuxt#hooks).

Create a new file `modules/newRelic.js` with the following content:

```
module.exports = function () {
  this.nuxt.hook("listen", () => {
    require("newrelic");
  });
};
```

Import the module in `nuxt.config.js`

```
modules: [
  "~/modules/newRelic.js"
]
```

Don't forget to install newrelic (`npm i newrelic`) and paste `newrelic.js` into the applications root folder.